# How can I import from a folder into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I want to import a class `Twitter` to my project..

I copied a folder to my project.
it is int
winterwell folder>>jtwitter folder>> Twitter class.

the winterwell folder is inside my project

I downloaded a jar file called jtwitter, unpacked it and tried to put it as a folder.. into eclipse. I dont know what is easier to import a jar file or import it as folders.. any method will solve my problem

Comment: it doesnt have a package declaration.. it is a folder (winterwell)>> with another folder (jtwitter)>> that has inside many classes..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's inside one of the project's source folders, just refresh the folder.

Otherwise, right-click the project, then select `Build Path > New Source Folder ...`

Or you can select `Import > General > File System` from the File menu.

Comment: i did what you told me, i imported it as jar. Build path>> link Source. found the jar file and imported it. i hope it did the same job.. :).. no mistake is shown by the way

Comment: @Dmitry sorry, I hadn't realized that you have a Jar file :-)

Comment: i edited my question, i have no idea how a jar file works. but the problem has been solved .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have an eclipse project, if so you will have at least one folder set up as a source folder in eclipse, if your java project is following any kind of conventions this folder will probably be called src on the filesystem. All you need to do is copy your Twitter class into any of the packages inside this source folder.

Alternatively you can add your new folder (jtwitter) as another source folder for your project will effectively achieve the same result.

Comment: it wont work well, cause the twitter class has got 50 classes in it..and when i add them to the source package..many of the classes show errors..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the folder shows up in your project Explorer, you should be able to right-click the folder, go down to Build Path and select "Use as Source Folder".

Answer (score 1):

right-click the project, then select `Build Path > New Source` Folder ...

Or you can `select Import > General > File System` from the File menu
 your project will imported